# How to change output of stored procedure on the fly in this query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I am trying to achieve something which I think is simply, but yet the syntax escapes me

Here's the query:

```
SET @T02_IDENTIFIANT_DSC = 'Hello ' + @Compagnie + ' '
INSERT INTO @TableDonnees
EXEC THE_DATABASE..spHeader @ValDate, @ValDate, '65', @T02_IDENTIFIANT_DSC, @RecCount
```

`spHeader` returns a record with two rows. How could I catch the value of one of the rows, modify it, then proceed to the INSERT ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert it into a temporary table, or a table variable. Make certain that the stored procedure supplies a way to identify the 'first' row. ORDER BY on a SELECT means nothing during insertion (in other words, it's not guaranteed, because it's not important to the machine).